# How to convert image to 1bpp byte Array in android Bitmap

Tags: android, binary, android-bitmap

> I have a image need to print in Bluetooth. So I need to convert image to 1bpp byte array which are values are 0 or 1 bytes. The below code is to convert and its not expected result as I want.

```
public static byte[] convert(Bitmap var0) {
        int var4 = var0.getWidth();
        int var5 = var0.getHeight();
        int var6 = var4 * var5 / 8;
        byte[] var7 = new byte[var6];
        byte var8 = 0;
        int var9 = 7;
        int var10 = 0;
        int[] var11 = new int[var4 * var5];
        var0.getPixels(var11, 0, var4, 0, 0, var4, var5);

        for(int var12 = 0; var12 < var11.length; ++var12) {
            int gray = 0;
            int var3 = Color.red(var11[var12]);
            int var2 = Color.green(var11[var12]);
            int var1 = Color.blue(var11[var12]);
            var3 = (int)(0.21D * (double)var3 + 0.71D * (double)var2 + 0.07D * (double)var1);

            if (var3 == 0) {
                var8 = a(var8, var9);
            }

            if (var3 > 128) {
                gray = 255;
            } else{
                gray = 0;
            }

            if (var9 == 0) {
                var9 = 7;
              //  var7[var10++] = var8;
                var7[var10++] = (byte)gray;
                var8 = 0;
            } else {
                --var9;
            }
        }

        return var7;
    }

    private static byte a(byte var0, int var1) {
        return (byte)(var0 | 1 << var1);
    }
```

Comment: What would be bpp?

Comment: And you do not start with an image but with a bitmap?

Comment: This is pretty unreadable code with var0 to var12.

Comment: bpp means bit per pixel

Comment: var0 to var12 are just referance variable

Comment: Again: Unreadable code. Please use normal readable variable names if you want help from normal code reading people. `1bpp byte array which are values are 0 or 1 bytes.` ??? 0 or 1 bytes ? I thought you wanted 0 or 1 bits. You wanna use one byte per bit? Pretty unclear too.

Comment: Sorry...its 0 or 1 bit and 1 bit per pixel and i am not clear about code forget it. IF you have any code about converting bitmap to 1bpp help me.

Comment: The is bitmap contains only black and white pixel

Comment: `i am not clear about code forget i` I will.